# Two-factor Authentication closed loop. Devices can't approve each other!

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, macos, two-factor-authentication

After recently updating iOS on my iPhone I was asked to approve my iPhone from another Apple device of mine. I believe an approval code was sent that I never received because it was sent to the device I am trying to approve. I saw my phone number appear on the screen, and confirmed it because it is my current number, not realizing where this would lead.

I can't approve my iPhone from my Mac because it's not running El Capitan yet. I have now started a lengthy Time Machine backup and am looking into the steps for a clean install since the Mac has performance issues that a standard update will likely not solve. This had to be done anyway, but it's going to be a process, and I still don't know if my iPhone will trust my Mac since the Mac doesn't have an existing history of 2FA usage.

I can't approve my iPhone from the household iPad because it uses another family member's account for iCloud. I hoped that because I make iTunes purchases on the iPad with my Apple ID that the iPhone would trust it, but it does not. In fact, the opposite has happened - after signing in with a now-suspect Apple ID the iPad is now also waiting for approval and refusing to trust the iPhone.

I cannot log into icloud.com for the same reason, so there's no hope of authenticating from there.

This has become a nightmare spiraling out of control, with my Apple devices all asking to be approved and none of them trusting each other. What can I do to prove that I am me, and get my iCloud and devices functioning again?

Comment: When you enabled 2FA, didn't they give you a recovery key (begins with RK-) to store in case this issue happened?

Comment: @Rajiv I think the recovery key is what was supposed to be sent to my iPhone, but I couldn't receive it. Is there a step where the user must confirm that the key has been received by entering it somewhere, or do they just assume the user received it? If it is the latter, I think I never received it.

Comment: There's also a recovery key that, when you set up 2FA, should be printed out and saved somewhere safe.

Answer (score 3):

If you select your phone number, your phone will receive the text and automatically fill in the code for you. I do not believe that macs are able to receive 2FA codes.

Comment: This has worked for me in the past

Answer (score 1):

HEYYYY!!! **I figured it out**! So what you have to do is sign into your Apple ID account from the **apple website**. This is from the **account manage page**. Next scroll down to and make sure you have a reliable recovery email...if not change it. Next under "**Security**" click the edit button at the top right. After doing so turn off "**Two-Factor Authentication** "... once you press this you will have to set up some recovery question and answers. After this apple will make you select your **recovery email** so they can lastly send a 6 digit code to confirm that you are turning the Two-factor Authentication off. That pretty much completes it... you should be out of the loop.

I do have a MacBook and I was stuck in the loop hole along with my iPhone. This one adjustment worked for both of my devices.

Comment: I am not able to deselect the 2 factor authentication in the account. How to solve this?